# How to Scale Mobile Site to Fit Many Screen sizes and Devices

Tags: css, mobile, cross-platform, scale

So I'm developing one of my first mobile versions of a site, and I'm coming up against what seems to me to be a very difficult issue about layout and scaling.

How can I make a mobile site that will look good on a wide variety of devices (from a 3.7" droid to a 9.7" iPad)?

And then how to make it look good in portrait and landscape?

Right now I'm using the "background-size" CSS3 property set to "cover" to scale the background, and then using some JS to scale the content based on screen size.

Although I see several SO questions on the subject, none seem to give me the insight I need.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

---

You can check out my progress at http://danielcampbell.net/RKAdler/

To preview my progress as it may look on a mobile:

Open it on your cell or download a mobile visualizer like the [Ripple extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) for Chrome

After install go to the RK Adler site and enable Ripple by clicking on its icon @ the top right and selecting "enable".

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using pixels for you major layout(s). For example instead of defining the width and height for the #wrapper element use 100%. Everything in this element that is sized using percentages will scale with it.

You should check some resources out on reponsive webdesign, lately they've been popping up like muchrooms:)

Check out these sites: 
[Slideshow by Netlash](http://www.slideshare.net/netlash/responsive-webdesign-10048132)

[A great example and slideshow about it](http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/10/11/responsive-awareness/) definitely check out their code of the demo

[A google search](http://www.google.be/search?q=responsive%20webdesign) - **Google is your friend!**

Comment: Thanks Stijn_d for the response.  I _do_ know how to use Google. Sometimes you need a little bit of human conversation to help you along the way, though ;p